# Nvidia driver problems can not switch between gpu's

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia, xubuntu, gpu

I just installed xubuntu but I a problem I don't see the prime profile option in "nvidia x settings" so I can not switch between my gpu's

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMSVn.png

Output when I run `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Skylake Integrated Graphics
    Kernel modules: i915_bpo
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Specs:

```
CPU
    Intel Core i7 6700HQ @ 2.60GHz  44 °C
    Skylake 14nm Technology
RAM
    16.0GB
Motherboard
    ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. GL552VW (U3E1)
Graphics
    Generic PnP Monitor (1920x1080@60Hz)
    Intel HD Graphics 530 (ASUStek Computer Inc)
    4095MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M (ASUStek Computer Inc)   50 °C
    ForceWare version: 372.54
    SLI Disabled
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gtf 1600 900 60 -x

xrandr --newmode "1600x900" 119.00  1600 1696 1864 2128  900 901 904  932  -HSync +Vsync

xrandr --addmode VGA1 1600x900

xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1600x900
```

Adjust the number 1600 900 with what u want.

Comment: Hi I ran your commands as you stated but I got an error when I tried this line:  "xrandr --newmode "1920x1080" 119.00  1600 1696 1864 2128  900 901 904  932  -HSync +Vsync". The error: xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default.

Comment: try to Run it as root

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help I fixed the resolution! I only need to fix the nvidia problem now...